# XML Recursive Node Parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, recursion

I've been trying to find a solution, searching through the web, and through many blogs, forums and websites and I'm still stuck with this issue.

I have a XML source like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
   <level_one>
      <level_two>
         #text
      </level_two>
      <level_two>
         #text
      </level_two>
   </level_one>
</root>
```

Then, in Java I'm trying to parse this XML file in a recursive way. This is my function:

```
public void parseXML(Node root, Node parent)
{
   if (root.hasChildNodes())
   {
      NodeList childrens = root.getChildNodes();
      for (int i = 0; childrens.getLength(); i++)
      {
            parseXML(childrens.item(i), root);           
      }//for
   }//fi:root_childrens
   else
      System.println.out(parent.getNodeName()+"::"+root.getNodeValue());
}
```

Once, when I've loaded the XML file, I do:

```
xmlDoc.normalize();
parseXML(xmlDoc.getFirstChild(), null);
```

OK, this works ... more or less.
Now, the response I'm getting is the following:

```
root:: //OK
level_one:: //OK
level_two::#text //OK
level_one:: //WRONG: should not appear any more
level_two::#text //OK
level_one:: //WRONG: should not appear any more
root:: //WRONG: should not appear any more
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
import javax.xml.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT 1: **FYI. The XML files goes deeper than 2 levels.**

EDIT 2: If I change **parent.getNodeName()** to **root.getNodeName()**, I get the following response:

```
#text::
#text::
#text::
...
```

Comment: sorry it's my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your program is displaying the empty text nodes that contains spaces like: "\n     "

Your xml may be viewed like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>[A node that contains "\n    "]
   <level_one>[A node that contains "\n    "]
      <level_two>
         #text
      </level_two>
      <level_two>
         #text
      </level_two>[A node that contains "\n    "]
   </level_one>[A node that contains "\n    "]
</root>
```

It is the reason why the nodes are displayed twice.

To obtains your desired output, you may write something like that:

```
public static void parseXML(Node node, Node parent)
{
   if (node.hasChildNodes())
   {
      System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
      NodeList childrens = node.getChildNodes();
      for (int i = 0; i < childrens.getLength(); i++)
      {
            parseXML(childrens.item(i), node);           
      }//for
   }//fi:root_childrens
   else {
      String nodeValue = node.getNodeValue().trim();
      if (nodeValue.length() > 0){
          System.out.println(parent.getNodeName() + "::" + nodeValue);
      }

   }
}
```

Which will print:

```
#document
root
level_one
level_two
level_two::#text
level_two
level_two::#text
```

Comment: Yes, there's the issue. Once I've cleaned the XML file from "\n" or "\t" special characters the code has work! Thanks for your help.